# segmentation fault that goes away by using iostream

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, iostream

So this is gnarly. I have a piece of code that used the Columbia Physics System c++ library. I get a segfault when I run it, most probably because the classes: CgArg, and vector f_field_in, etc are uninitialised. I used Valgrind and found that indeed the various arguments were pointing to invalid memory.

The strange this is that if I insert an iostream call anywhere in the two functions, the segfault goes away. I found out when I put flags in places to debug. It also doesn't segfault if I define an integer and write a simple cin >>. That's why I think it's something to do with iostream.

If you know of any reason why a call to iostream would somehow give pieces of code to the arguments, I'd be very thankful if you shared it with me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <config.h>
#include <util/lattice.h>
#include <util/dirac_op.h>
#include <util/gjp.h>
#include <interface.h>

#define CLOVER_MAT_SIZE 72

USING_NAMESPACE_CPS

// Same function for clover matrix and its inverse.
static
void interface(double *h_quda_clover, double *h_cps_clover)
{
  h_quda_clover[0]=h_cps_clover[0];  // c00_00_re = C0.x, A0
```

...and lots more of this stuff...

```
  h_quda_clover[35+36]=h_cps_clover[34+36];  // c32_31_im = C8.w, A5
}

static
void fill_h_clover_inv(Lattice &lat, int site[], double *h_quda_clover_inv_site)
{
  double h_cps_clover_inv[72];
  Vector *f_field_out, *f_field_in;
  CgArg *arg;
  CnvFrmType convert=CNV_FRM_NO;
  DiracOpClover dirac(lat,f_field_out,f_field_in,arg,convert);
  //cout << "B: " << site << endl;
  //cout << "B: site: " << site[0] << ' ' << site[1] << ' ' << site[2] << ' ' <<         site[3] << endl;
  dirac.SiteCloverMat(site,h_cps_clover_inv);
  interface(h_quda_clover_inv_site,h_cps_clover_inv);
}

void fill_h_clover_inv_all(Lattice &lat, double *h_quda_clover_inv, int parity)
{
  double *ptr=h_quda_clover_inv;
  int nsites[4];
  nsites[0]=GJP.XnodeSites();
  nsites[1]=GJP.YnodeSites();
  nsites[2]=GJP.ZnodeSites();
  nsites[3]=GJP.TnodeSites();
  int site[4];
  cout << "A: " << site << endl;
  for (site[3] = 0; site[3] < nsites[3]; ++(site[3])) {
    for (site[2] = 0; site[2] < nsites[2]; ++(site[2])) {
      for (site[1] = 0; site[1] < nsites[1]; ++(site[1])) {
        site[0] = (site[3] + site[2] + site[1] + parity)%2;
        for (; site[0] < nsites[0]; site[0] += 2) {
  //cout << "A: site: " << site[0] << ' ' << site[1] << ' ' << site[2] << ' ' <<     site[3] << endl;
          fill_h_clover_inv(lat,site,ptr);
          ptr += CLOVER_MAT_SIZE;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the conclusion that "it's something to do with iostream" *might* be a red herring. If you can mask the problem by rearranging things, or adding a variable or unnecessary I/O, this hints at a memory bug (buffer overrun or similar). I wouldn't necessarily zero in on iostream at this point.

Comment: What os is this on? Tried running it through valgrind memcheck?

Comment: It's running on Ubuntu 12.04. Furthermore, not every instance of iostream call prevents a segfault.

Comment: A segmentation fault happens when you attempt to access memory outside your program. By adding more code and more variables, the program's size increases and the "outside" shrinks. You are likely not fixing the problem, just hiding it.

Comment: It's a good idea to initialize variables, especially pointers, to something.  `f_field_out`, `f_field_in`, and `arg` seem particularly suspicious here.

Comment: Yeah. The strange thing is that using the IOstream and then using valgrind to see what the pointers are pointing to gives odd results. If no iostream is called, the pointers are null 0x800000000eb. But if an iostream is called, a random piece of memory is there instead.

Comment: When I initialise to NULL, there is an auto segfault elsewhere in the code. What we are doing here is fooling DiracOpClover into giving us its output, with out going through all the steps to generate the full input. It works fine if random memory is passed, but I don't know how that is happening.

Comment: +1 for having solved it yourself

Comment: I wish i had solved it! :) I just need to know a bit more about the stack and memory allocation. I just can't understand why a segmentation fault would go away if you print something to screen.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with some uninitialised arguments being passed to DiracOpClover. Once we initialised CgArg properly,

```
CgArg cg_arg;
cg_arg.mass=1.0
```

everything was hunky dory!!

Thank for the help everyone.